# Want to show custom Geodesic buffer points using local CSV in ArcGIS

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-arc-engine, geodesic-sphere, arcgis-runtime-net

I used the Geodesic buffers sample code of ArcGIS from the following link

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/ge_geodesic_buffers.html

Setup the proxy. it worked fine and showed all the points with features.

It was getting the points from this link  http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.csv"

but I wanted to show points from my own CSV file but I didn't find a way to do in this sample code, then I used CSVLayer to show points which worked fine to show my points but it doesn't have features what was in Geodesic buffer. I couldn't add feature layer to it because map didn't contain graphics.

Could you please provide me a way that I can show my own points, just like Geodesic buffer sample does?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET v100, you can parse csv file to get lat/lon values, use GeometryEngine.BufferGeodetic method and GraphicsOverlay to display result.

    `var overlay = MyMapView.GraphicsOverlays[0];
    foreach (var line in result)
    {
        var longitude = Convert.ToDouble(line["longitude"]);
        var latitude = Convert.ToDouble(line["latitude"]);
        var mp = new MapPoint(longitude, latitude, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
        var buffer = GeometryEngine.BufferGeodetic(mp, 2000, LinearUnits.Kilometers);
        var graphic = new Graphic(buffer, new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbolStyle.Solid, Colors.Blue, null));
        overlay.Graphics.Add(graphic);
    }`

Comment: I am not using any sdk